# Excel Signatures

Tags: excel, signature

We have an Excel file that grabs data from a database and displays data to the end user.  Simple.

What we want to do is automate the creation of the signature blocks based on the value in the Project Code field / cell B1 (see below).

[image: Excel File]

The file contains a hidden sheet that contains the desired values (see below).

[image: Signature Setup]

When using the MS Office signatures, we would like to automate the population of the Signature Setup dialog box with the information from the hidden sheet based on the Project Code Value.
[image: Dialog Box]

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at what you can do with the **Signature** object in Excel VBA. According to the [help file](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV805591499990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=12&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=e4e0dcc4%2Dfc8d%2D4619%2Dae43%2D8f3751948e1b) for this, using a **Signature** object along with the **SignatureSet** collection should provide some functionality for what you're trying to do here.